# SQL Server 2016 - Transpose column of integers to row by day

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to transpose one of the columns in the data date to a row of string and group by 2 other columns. My sample data consists of the following data:

[image]

I need the result to look like this:

[image]

That is all the LNs in one row per Employee code, per day.

I tried the below code -

```
DECLARE @Process_Conditions_Loans VARCHAR(500)

SELECT
    t1.EmplCode,
    t1.LogDate,
    @Process_Conditions_Loans = CONCAT(COALESCE(@Process_Conditions_Loans + ',', ''),PS2)
FROM
    #temp t1
WHERE
    LN IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY
    EmplCode, LogDate
```

But I am getting an error

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

I can not use `group_concat` since I am using SQL Server 2016.

Any help would be great appreciated.

Thanks,
JH

Comment: I am sorry, I mean SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the older form of string aggregation:

```
select emplcode, logdate,
       stuff( (select concat(', ', ln)
               from t
               where t.emplcode = el.emplcode and t.logdate = el.logdate
               order by ln
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 2, ''
            )
from (select distinct emplcode, logdate
      from t
     ) el
```

Comment: @JHegde . . . Can you set up a db fiddle to illustrate this?

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Thank you.

Comment: your code works great on my sample date. Just realized that the actual data has logdate with timestamp which is messing it up. Thanks so much for the code, appreciate it!